# Why does the onclick function run on onclick, but not when I call it manually?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code

```
 // Register onclick
 var old_onclick = link.onclick;

 link.onclick = function() {
  astr_track_action(param);

  if(typeof(old_onclick) == "function")
   old_onclick();
 }
```

And this is the html

```
<a onclick="alert('hello!');" href="http://www.google.com?acme=link&foo=bar">To google!</a>
```

When I click the link, the alert pops up. But when I override the onclick with my JS code, the alert does **not** pop up.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: I just want to add, I have debugged and confirmed that `old_onclick()` is run, but no alert message shows up.

---

Edit: Here is the full code from the loop start. I don't see how it's relevant, but it was requested:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++)
{
    var link = document.links[i];
    var eventlink = link.href.split("acme=");

    if(eventlink.length > 1)
    {
        var param = eventlink[1].split("&")[0];
        var newlink = link.href;

        // Register onclick
        var old_onclick = link.onclick;

        link.onclick = function() {
            astr_track_action(param);

            if(typeof(old_onclick) == "function")
                old_onclick();
        }
```

Comment: Is `astr_track_action` defined? Is `param` defined somewhere? Is `astr_track_action` executed successful? What happens if you comment this line?

Comment: Is that the actual code? Could you set up a jsfiddle example to show us?

Comment: @Felix Kling Yes, I have debugged and confirmed that old_onclick() is run at onclick.
@lonesomeday Yes, that is the actual code, copied straight out of Eclipse.

Comment: And what's the code for generating `link`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating functions in a loop. `old_onclick` will point to the click handler of the last element you loop over (because upon execution, the click handlers will access `old_onclick` when the loop already finished).
You have to capture the value by e.g. using an immediate function:

```
var old_onclick = link.onclick;

link.onclick = (function(old_onclick) {
    return function() {
        astr_track_action(param);

        if(typeof(old_onclick) == "function")
                 old_onclick();
        }
    };
 }(old_onclick));
```

JavaScript has no block scope, only function scope. I.e.

```
for(...) {
    var foo = something;
}
```

is the same as

```
var foo;
for(...) {
    foo = something;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as expected:

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/8RJ5y/

Answer (score 0):

It does work, so far as I can tell: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf26V/)

Note that, if you are doing anything using `this`, you will need to use `apply`, rather than just invoking the function normally:

```
if (typeof(old_onclick) == 'function') {
    old_onclick.apply(this, arguments);
}
```